# Change the appearance of commas in a certain font

Tags: fonts, punctuation

I'm using the `kerkis` font, which I love everything about *except* for the commas.  (The curl of the commas is very small, making them appear like periods unless you look very closely.)

Is there a way to change how the commas look, within this font?

[image: commas]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{kmath, kerkis}
\begin{document}
It's hard to tell apart commas, and periods.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of changing the comma on the macro level, with potentially hazardous results, you could also use virtual fonts. While this is transparent to TeX, and therefore completely robust, it is unfortunately also a lot more complicated. These are the steps:

1. Look into the font definition file `ot1mak.fd` (whose location is recorded in the `log` file) to see which font we actually want to modify. There we find, among others, the line

   ```
   \DeclareFontShape{OT1}{mak}{m}{n}{<-> s * [0.90] k8a}{}
   ```

   [From here on, I assume that you are in the current directory of your TeX file.]
2. Transform the (already existing) virtual font (which resides in `<TEXMF>/fonts/vf/public/kerkis/`) into human-readable form. (Actually, you don't even need to know where the `vf` file is, as `vftovp` should be able to find it by itself.)

   ```
   vftovp k8a > k8a.vpl
   ```
3. We open this new file `k8a.vpl` and search for the definition of the comma, finding these lines:

   ```
   (CHARACTER O 54
      (CHARWD R 0.32)
      (CHARHT R 0.114)
      (CHARDP R 0.111)
      (MAP
         (SETCHAR O 54)
         )
      )
   ```

   (The `O` means that the numbers are octal.)
4. Instead of using a comma from a different font, it might be better to take the apostrophe from the same font, shifted down, so that the appearance matches. The apostrophe is in slot `O 47`, so we replace the above line `(SETCHAR O 54)` with: `(MOVEDOWN R .6) (SETCHAR O 47)`. (The `R` is for "real number", so that the glyph will be shifted down by 0.6 design units, which seems approximately right.)
5. Since the lower part of the semicolon has the same shape as the comma, it wouldn't match anymore with the lowered apostrophe. Therefore, we could additionally construct the semicolon from an apostrophe (shifted down) and a period (shifted up):

   ```
   (CHARACTER O 73
      (CHARWD R 0.32)
      (CHARHT R 0.4865)
      (CHARDP R 0.111)
      (MAP
         (PUSH) (MOVEUP R .37) (SETCHAR O 56) (POP)
         (MOVEDOWN R .6) (SETCHAR O 47)
         )
      )
   ```
6. Translate the `vpl` file back to `vf` and accompanying `tfm` files:

   ```
   vptovf k8a
   ```

For other font shapes you would proceed accordingly, for example for the italic shape (`ki8a`):

```
vftovp ki8a > ki8a.vpl
```

Edit the comma and semicolon, e.g.:

```
(CHARACTER O 54
   (CHARWD R 0.3)
   (CHARHT R 0.116)
   (CHARDP R 0.1125)
   (MAP
      (MOVELEFT R .12) (MOVEDOWN R .6) (SETCHAR O 47)
      )
   )

 ....

(CHARACTER O 73
   (CHARWD R 0.3)
   (CHARHT R 0.4925)
   (CHARDP R 0.1125)
   (MAP
      (PUSH) (MOVERIGHT R .06) (MOVEUP R .37) (SETCHAR O 56) (POP)
      (MOVELEFT R .12) (MOVEDOWN R .6) (SETCHAR O 47)
      )
   )
```

and finally:

```
vptovf ki8a
```

---

If the newly created `tfm` and `vf` files are in the working directory, they will be picked up before the ones distributed with `kerkis`. Et voilà, the apostrophe-comma and semicolon:

[image: comma+semicolon]

Unfortunately, you would have to repeat this procedure for every single font you are using (italic, small caps etc.), in all encodings.

Comment: Is there a way to do this within the TeX code? I don't know where this file is located.

Comment: @jamaicanworm No, this is not possible within TeX. Does the update of the answer help?

Comment: How would you make this change happen also for the `\emph` version of the `kerkis` font?

Comment: @jamaicanworm see my update

Comment: You can't do this within the TeX code of your document but you could use TeX to make the changes. That is, you could use TeX to produce the required virtual fonts, making the changes to the comma and semicolon. You can then write a file to basically set up all of the virtual fonts you want by calling the same code repeatedly. This would not be at all dangerous and it would not require replacing existing files. Basically, you could install the modified version as a new font, from TeX's point of view. But it would require additional files so I don't know if it would be of interest or not.

Answer (score 4):

It is only a draft:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{kmath, kerkis}

\font\commaf=cmr11
\begin{document}
It's hard to tell apart commas, and periods.

It's hard to tell apart commas{\commaf,} and periods.

If there will be no math:

\def\cmcomma{{\commaf,}}
\let\commasign\cmcomma
\catcode`\,=13
%\def,{\commasign}
\def,{\cmcomma}


It's hard to tell apart commas, and periods.

But beware: $(a,b)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Presumably you could write macro to globally replace all my instances of `,` with `{\commaf,}`?

Comment: @jamaicanworm The `,` after `If there will be no math` IS such a macro. However it is only a sketch, because, as it is shown, it destroys math appearance.

Comment: That approach seems really dangerous. Commas play an important role in TeX, namely as list delimiters. Making the comma character active is surely not a good idea, because it's going to break pretty much everything.

Comment: @Jubobs Certainly. Hence I am expecting additional information from OP. For a pure text is is enough, for more advanced usage much more should be done.

Comment: If such a macro is not a good idea, is there a way to write a piece of code that will just change the appearance of commas (without needing to replace every instance of `,`)?

Comment: This doesn't slant the comma. E.g. in `\emph{commas,}`.

Comment: @jamaicanworm Such a macro may be a good idea with some restrictions. If you have an example of text for which you need it, it helps developing my draft.

Answer (score 4):

Here is yet another solution, which requires luatex, using OpenType font feature files which, amazingly, also work with Type1 fonts. Save the following as `kerkis.fea`:

```
languagesystem DFLT dflt;
languagesystem latn dflt;

lookup SHIFT_N { # shift the apostrophe down and add some space on the right
  pos quoteright <0 -600 60 0> ;
} SHIFT_N ;

lookup SHIFT_I { # additionally shift a bit to the left
  pos quoteright <-120 -600 -60 0> ;
} SHIFT_I ;

lookup REPLACE {
  sub comma by quoteright ;
} REPLACE ;

feature comn {
  lookup REPLACE ;
  lookup SHIFT_N ;
} comn ;

feature comi {
  lookup REPLACE ;
  lookup SHIFT_I ;
} comi ;
```

Your document (to be compiled with `lualatex`) could then look like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{kmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
        Ligatures=TeX,
        FeatureFile=kerkis.fea,
        % with Type1 fonts, fontspec doesn't seem to be able to 
        % automatically detect the other shapes, so we specify them:
        ItalicFont=Kerkis-Italic.pfb,
        SmallCapsFont=Kerkis-SmallCaps.pfb,
        BoldFont=Kerkis-Bold.pfb,
        BoldItalicFont=Kerkis-BoldItalic.pfb,
        % add the comma replacement feature 
        UprightFeatures={RawFeature=+comn},
        ItalicFeatures={RawFeature=+comi}]
        {Kerkis.pfb}
\begin{document}
It's hard to tell apart commas, and; periods.

\textit{It's hard to tell apart commas, and; periods.}
\end{document}
```

[image: comma with luatex]

Note that you must not use the quoteright character (`’`) in your document, as this would also be shifted down, but fortunately with `Ligatures=TeX` you can simply write `'` instead.

In contrast to the solution with virtual fonts, there doesn't seem to be a way to also change the semicolon.

And another caveat: as luatex isn't quite the drop-in replacement for pdftex which it was initially announced to become, some other things may break in your document.

Comment: Does compiling with `pdftex` automatically make the `luatex` stuff work?

Comment: @jamaicanworm No, you would run `lualatex` _instead of_ `pdflatex`.

Comment: Thank you Robert! This answer wins the bounty, for answering the question given the bounty-imposed parameters. However, your other answer seems to be more popular and thus will be accepted.